# Visual Studio 2012 fails to load some projects and then hangs (is busy)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a solution consisting of 4 projects and am happily editing this at work on a Windows 7 machine running VS 2012, storing my code in TFS+Git in the cloud.

However, at home after pulling down the solution I cannot get Visual Studio 2012 on my home PC to open the project files.

I get the "solution loading..." message and (load failed) on 3 out of the 4 projects.

Now the differences are at work I run Windows 7 64-bit, at home Windows 8.
At work I run the 64-bit version of VS2012, at home the 32-bit.

Maybe that's enough to mess things up, maybe I've referenced something on my 64-bit instance that my home PC does not have, but other than that the machines are patched with Update 3 of VS 2012.

What can I do to discover what VS is doing?  Any trace options I can switch on?
I've deleted everything, pulled the solution down to no avail.

Comment: Does your project configuration (Debug, Release, etc.) specify 32-bit or 64-bit explicitly?

Comment: VS does not have 64 bit version. Do you see anything special in output window?

Comment: Project configuration is "Any CPU" and nothing appears in the Output window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to hang ("project initializing...") on projects that had no packages.
Uninstalling NuGet appears to resolve the initial problem and I can then open the solution.
Build -> then install NuGet back again ensuring automatic download of missing packages is switched off.
VS then moaned about missing Microsoft.Build.1.7 dll, so manually added the required package from Console Manager.
Eventually got it back working again.

Hope that helps anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  I had just updated Nuget when I began to see projects hang at "initializing".

Comment: It works like a charm for me and saved many hours I used to spent for solving this.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, but uninstalling NuGet didn't help. VS would hang with (initializing...) next to one project and I'd have to kill it. Your solution got me thinking, so I removed packages folder from the solution folder. I started VS, made sure automatic download is checked in NuGet options, and then loaded the solution with no issues. Rebuilding the solution prompted NuGet to restore packages, and all was well again.

Comment: brilliant! Worked for me!

Comment: It works like a charm for me and saved many hours I used to spent for solving this.