# VS2015 solution hangs on loading

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution that hangs every time I load it up.

I have deleted the .vs directory which means it will load once but the next time it hangs again.

If I leave it long enough it says Visual Studio is busy ...

Any help?

Edit: More info. I can load each project individually without a problem. It is only when I load the solution which contains all 3 projects that it hangs on loading.

Comment: Try Funnel extension - it will allow you to load only some of the projects: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DimitriDering.Funnel

Comment: I need to load the other projects. I have three projects in the solution all relatively new. Why are people downvoting this?

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled that might does a lot of processing on the projects like R#? Try disabling them

Comment: No not really. One is an older project (About 2 years old not ancient) and the other two are both recent. 

The solution just has all of them in one place and a Web Project which has nothing in it. 

It gets stuck on loading unless I delete the .vs folder within the solution directory. And then the next time I load it I have to delete that directory again.

Comment: .vs should be there as this is something where .vs keeps it's stuff it will get recreated. Is this project like TFS based or any other repository? Maybe it hangs on some network access? It's strange that VS hangs on such small project.

Comment: It's using Git (Source Tree as the UI) with BitBucket as the repo but it commits locally so it isn't that.

Comment: My VS sometimes hangs with git plugin in VS being enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

I found this answer - [Visual Studio 2012 fails to load some projects and then hangs (is busy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934866/visual-studio-2012-fails-to-load-some-projects-and-then-hangs-is-busy)

I had to delete the Nuget packages folder and make sure I had restore nuget packages enabled.